# Socket receiving wrong data with concurrent FTP transfer

Tags: c++, sockets, curl, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

There is this nasty thread (the client) that is waiting for events from a remote device (the server). The events are received through a TCP socket by a dedicated network (I have to assign a static IP). The operation is not a blocking one, but a polling (`select` + `recv`). For a certain operation, the thread starts a `FTP` transfer with the device using the `CURL` library. Then, sometimes, instead of the next normal operation, we are receiving garbage. The behaviour is reproductible on two of three computers, systematically. On one of them it works if the device is connect directly through the network port, but not if through a network-USB adapter (which allows the Internet connection). On the other side, the adapter works very well, in this situation, on another computer. *If we eliminate the FTP transfer, all works fine.* The behaviour is identical with the used CURL version and with the last one, 7.40.

I'm a maintainer here, there's an old gigantic project, I can hardly change/rewrite things, particularly in this situation with this piece of code that apparently worked for several years (although some problems were signaled) and with just almost two months before beta. But I have to solve this and I would change the operation from polling to blocking if necessary, by exemple. Other colleagues were already seen the code, `Application Verifier` is detecting nothing (anymore), the buffer received from recv is already corrupted, `Wireshark` says that we are receiving the correct packets - nothing! Debugging is a little bit difficult as there's no debugging setup for this enormous "application" and by remote debugging and some "well chosen" breakpoints ... the wrong behaviour disappears. I tried most of the usual (past winning) paths for almost two weeks, the remaining ones don't look too promising either - and they all take time: 1) directly debugging one of the computers (if debug reproductible and after installing VS, get the entire code from the server) - I have no idea what to still try 2) writing the "right" code to do it in a separate project (already started somehow) 3) an alternative llvm build (huge effort).

Any idea is appreciated, I'll be glad to react to any clarification demand.

**EDIT**
We reproduced the situation in a minimal test program. It happens through an USB - network adapter on two computers from the three tried.
We get two commands from our device through a TCP socket. We read only the first one (1 byte), we make the FTP transfer using the CURL library, then we read the other one (7 bytes), but there's only garbage. If we switch the FTP call with the reading of the second command, everything is fine, even in an endless loop. Wireshark shows that the data (7 bytes) comes correctly, so it's obvious that something is happening during the CURL FTP transfer. But how can it affect the unrelated socket? 
The current step is to identify the CURL call that damages our socket.

**EDIT 2**
We didn't precisely identify the dirty CURL call because ... it is not a fixed point. We do this identification by `recv(..., MSG_PEEK)` and by trace, and sometimes it can be between two `printf` instructions, though it is around the same code area. IMHO, this is only possible because some CURL connect call spawns another thread (named `_SockAsyncThread@4`, apparently internally used by Windows) that could alter the stack of our socket. By adding a `Sleep(1500)` in some places ... it works. The same "not working" behavior with the 64-bit builds. While it never works with CURL, by replacing it with `FtpGetFile`, it works in a loop with the exception ... of the first call :(. My thoughts are that "D-Link DUB-E100 USB 2.0 Fast Ethernet Adapter" has some serious problems within its driver (up-to-date, the Windows 7 version is the same with the Vista one, BTW). A workaround seems to me to first read the notifications on our socket and just afterwards process them. Or maybe just use another thread to do the FTP work.

Comment: "On the other side, the adapter works very well, in this situation, on another computer" - might be worth examining the computer that works for differences from the two that don't, e.g., network driver versions, anti-virus software, firmware revisions, firewall configuration, that sort of thing.

Comment: The current process is to compare the logs (internal, Wireshark) on the computer where we identified both behaviors: it works by the direct connection and it doesn't by the adapter.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The Windows firewall might be an idea even if I cannot see how it can affect the behavior in this way. Funny thing, only the computer that works has antivirus software.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a bug in the network driver for the USB adapter, or perhaps even in the USB bus drivers.  Driver bugs can be tricky to reproduce, the reason the problem doesn't exhibit on the third computer might be something that would seem completely irrelevant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston This is our latest idea, but I'm not convinced that the sockets stack is managed by the driver - I always thought it is the WIndows kernel itself

Comment: @HarryJohnston I had a little time for review and I can confirm you that the general conclusion was that "D-Link DUB-E100 USB 2.0 Fast Ethernet Adapter" has a bug in the network driver. We came with a workaround for our case (skipped that particular FTP transaction). 
Please answer the question (you already had the idea on Jan 21 `15) so I can "close" this question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those rare questions where the problem really was a bug in someone else's code; the OP has confirmed that the ethernet device driver was faulty.